# Using ubuntu server as host for mac/windows

Tags: server

I hate to be *that guy* and ask a question that may have been asked before, but I have a specific usage case in mind and feel the question is justified.

So here goes. I run a tiny app development company and I also do contracting work.
I have a bunch of folders and code on my iMac and macbook pro and I also use HG version control via bitbucket for projects.

I have installed ubuntu server 12.x (the latest version) on a quad core pc with about 1.5tb of storage space (eventually raising to 2.5tb) and also plan to install virtual box to run windows 8 also.

Questions:

1. I want to be able to control ubuntu server via vnc from my mac or macbook (i hear chicken vnc is good) because the computer resides in an office that is about as warm as Antarctica. Best options?
2. I want to store all of my code, graphical and audio assets and some other work related things on the ubuntu server and work off the files contained on it on my iMac or mac. These code project's generally never reach over 250mb (that's everything, code files are generally < 50kb). Also plan to dropbox backup the project folder part of ubuntu that I will create.

   Are there any shortcomings about doing this that I should be aware of?

   The goal is to still use version control to manage these projects but to have things current at all times when working on either mac or any future computer.
3. Speed. Will it be fast enough to access and work off via wifi? I think yes but having a second opinion never hurts.

---

I hope my questions make sense and thank anyone who can offer advice so much in advance. I have the basics set up now and I don't want to waste time doing it wrong a hundred times when I can do it right the first time with some sound advice.

PS: I have used Linux and ubuntu for roughly 2 years in the past (about 3 years ago) and I am a programmer by trade so I am not afraid of the command line ;)

Answer (score 0):

The latest version of Ubuntu Server is 12.10, but this question is tagged with 12.04.

Does Ubuntu Server have a GUI for the use of VNC? No. So, are you going to jump hoops to get this done? Just using SSH is the normal method.

Dropbox/Ubuntu One may be  difficult to use on a headless server. Perhaps you could rsync from the server to one of your Macs or use a different, better backup solution.

The Mac is Darwin Unix so you could use NFS for file sharing, or maybe your IDE can log in via SFTP, or you could even use Samba because Windows is in the scenario.

Yes, it will be fast enough. I do it. :)